# Providers for lazy loading in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, lazy-loading, guice

In [the official document](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders), I read an article about Providers for lazy loading.  However, I can't understand why this below code means the delay of creating a provider because I can't find any annotation or any code which is corresponding with the lazy loading.
And the code is this code.

```
public class DatabaseTransactionLog implements TransactionLog {

  private final Provider<Connection> connectionProvider;

  @Inject
  public DatabaseTransactionLog(Provider<Connection> connectionProvider) {
    this.connectionProvider = connectionProvider;
  }

  public void logChargeResult(ChargeResult result) {
    /* only write failed charges to the database */
    if (!result.wasSuccessful()) {
      Connection connection = connectionProvider.get();
    }
  }
```

Where in the world can we see the special point which causes a delay of loading?

Comment: Normally when a dependency is satisfied, the object needed is created.  For Providers the object needed is not created until `get()` is called, which may be much much later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

creating a connection may be expensive, and it may not alway be needed. Therefore, rather than creating a connection at injection time, the guice framework allows the injection of a 'provider', which will create the dependency when the `get()` method is called.

The delay is in the way you call `provider.get()`, and it's delayed relative to the time the constructors are called for each dependency. In the example you have, the constructor for `DatabaseTransactionLog` gets called, but no connection is created at that time. A `Connection` is only created when the method `logChargeResult` is called (because of the `provider.get()` call in it).